# Bulk create api with spring boot

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to come up with the proper way to create an end point that gives the option to create a single object or a list of it.
I'm using spring-boot framework. How do I offer both options with the same end point? and also is the proper way to do it with the same end point name?

Thanks!

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void save(@RequestBody() final Person person)
```

or

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void save(@RequestBody() final List<Person> persons)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the single object as a list with one element, and keep that handler method. That's a little challenging for the client though, but if they don't care, it's the simplest option. Otherwise, you can accept the request body as a string and try to figure out whether it's meant to be a single object or a list and act accordingly.

Comment: I meant to say it would be one or the other method but not both.
Yes, a list can be used and the client needs to adapt but I would imagine that this is a standard use case and there must be a best practice for it.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SophianAchiba There's no "best practice" for this because it's not a design pattern question, it's a simple choice question. There are best practices for use of URI patterns and HTTP verbs and RMM, none of which are relevant for your question. [Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) has one of the best resources on REST API design. As for your case, a collection can be treated as a resource just like an individual object, and your POST method would return the newly created URI in the `Location` header. You're welcome,